# CentOS 7 touchpad gestures for Two Finger Scrolling and etc

Tags: linux, centos, gnome, gnome3

I have CentOS 7 laptop environment for development.
I want my touchpad to have touchpad gestures like two Finger Scrolling(vertical and horizontal) or edge scrolling and double-tap.
How to configure a touchpad for Two Finger Scroll? And touchpad gestures drivers?

Dell Latitude 3410 14" laptop.
OS is CentOS 7.
GNOME 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two finger scrolling not working on Lenovo ThinkPad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391804/two-finger-scrolling-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad)

Comment: Can you edit your post to indicate which hardware you are using?